# tbb determines incorrect concurrency

Tags: multithreading, tbb, dlib, parallel.for

[image]

I am using tbb for parallelization and I have encountered an annoying issue.

I use tbb::parallel_for and the algorithm is running on a single thread.

if I print

```
std::cout << tbb::task_scheduler_init::default_num_threads() << std::endl;
```

it reports `1`.

If I manually override the concurrency by:

```
 tbb::task_scheduler_init guard(std::thread::hardware_concurrency());
```

tbb creates the appropriate number of threads, but the parallel_for **still schedules all work on a single thread (not even switching between the cores)**. All this happens on a 16+ thread machine.

Furthermore `top` reports `100%` cpu usage (instead of the correct `1600%`) **and** `16` average load. On the image You can see that the blue core is saturated, while the rest of the cores run idle sometimes (the snapshot is of my desktop not the 16+ core server, but the effect is similar).

I am using `tbb-2018_U5` opensuse 15 and `dlib`

Is this a bug?

Comment: I have managed to find out that the process' affinity mask is 1: taskset -p 15299
pid 15299's current affinity mask: 1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, the calling thread is bound to one core by `dlib`. Consider this [answer](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-threading-building-blocks/topic/777514#comment-1921887).

UPDATE: In accordance with [#1422](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/1422) `dlib` does not affect affinity masks.

Comment: Hello I have found this thread but I have no idea what does it mean. I have compiled `dlib` from source, but it has no reference (in the source code) to tbb. Should I be looking for some linux API calls?

Comment: It looks like that `dlib` changes the process/thread mask with OS API (TBB does not have API to change affinity). However, TBB respects OS settings for affinity mask and binds its own thread pool in accordance with the mask.

Comment: Dlib doesn't sent any thread masks for affinities or anything like that.

Comment: What I can add to the discussion is that dlib::parallel_for behaves similar way, that is it executes all the chunks on a single core.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to work around the issue, by forcing the process' affinity. In `Linux` you write:

```
cpu_set_t mask;
int       status;
CPU_ZERO(&mask);
const auto NUMCORES = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
for (int64_t core = 0; core < NUMCORES; core++) CPU_SET(core, &mask);
sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &mask);
```

on the beginning of the main function, and the threads scale as predicted.

Comment: Could you share minimal reproducer, or pseudo-code how you use `dlib` and `tbb`, please?